# I am getting this error while importing keras to shell, while I have installed tensorflow of version 2.4.1 and keras 2.4.3

Tags: tensorflow

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:58:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tensorflow
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "C:\Users\vbhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
> > > from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> > > ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\vbhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 41, in 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as *module_util
File "C:\Users\vbhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init**.py", line 39, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\vbhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\vbhav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Microsoft C++ redistributable application. And this error was fixed.
https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe